# How to test methods that deal with SQLite database in android?

Tags: android, junit, easymock, android-sqlite

I have made an application that deals with SQLite database by opening, retrieving data from, and inserting data to it. Now I want to test my methods.

So , I have two classes, one "`SQLiteHelper`" which extends `SQLiteOpenHelper` to open,create,and upgrade the database, and the other is a `DataSource` class, that makes an `SQLiteDatabase` object,and contains all my methods that deals with the database.

So for calling any method I need to call the open method in the `SQLiteHelper` class, catch the result in an `SQLiteDatabse` object,then make an object of the `DataSource` class,and finally call the method( which contains a cursor as a result of a rawquery for example).

I know that it won't work with simple JUnit test, and I've read about Mock Objects, but I still don't understand how I can use it in my case.

Comment: "the other is a DataSource class, that makes an SQLiteDatabase object" - this is not clear. `SQLiteHelper` should create `SQLiteDatabase` object. Can you provide some code of your `DataSource` class to clarify the problem.

Comment: public class DataSource {
 private static SQLiteHelper dbHelper = null;
 SQLiteDatabase database;public void openDatabase(Context context) {
  if (dbHelper == null) {
   dbHelper = new SQLiteHelper(context);
   dbHelper.openDataBase(SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
   database = dbHelper.myDataBase;
  }
 }

Comment: Oh, I see. Nothing important in this class. Check my answer anyway

Comment: If you are satisfied with answer, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I know that it won't work with simple JUnit test

It will. Just call your methods as usual and check results for correctness.

The only important thing is that you should prefer to use [`IsolatedContext`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/IsolatedContext.html) for your database creation. In this case your original database file from the app will remain unmodified. All tests will work with separate testing database file which can be modified or even deleted as many times as you want.

You can acquire proper `IsolatedContext` from [`ProviderTestCase2`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/ProviderTestCase2.html). (You can also look `ProviderTestCase2` sources to understand how it works.)

Comment: AndroidTestCase isn't a simple "JUnit" test, you can't run it on the JVM.